# Difference between @ConditionalOnClass , @ConditionalOnMissingClass

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-annotations

Difference between @ConditionalOnClass, @ConditionalOnMissingClass?

Can someone give me the difference between these annotations?

Comment: Have you tried to like google the effects of both annotations?

Answer (score 1):

Spring `@ConditionalOnClass` and `@ConditionalOnMissingClass` annotations let `@Configuration` classes be included based on the presence or absence of specific classes. So `@ConditionalOnClass` loads a bean only if a certain class is on the classpath and `@ConditionalOnMissingClass` loads a bean only if a certain class is not on the classpath.

More [here](https://roytuts.com/spring-conditionalonclass-and-conditionalonmissingclass/)

Answer (score 0):

You can mark a bean class with any of the annotations, but they do opposite things. `@ConditionalOnClass` includes bean of marked class if annotation's parameter is present on classpath. Whereas `@ConditionalOnMissingClass` includes it if the class is absent.

These annotations are important part of autoconfiguration process when Spring chooses appropriate bean type based on application classpath.

Answer (score 0):

With these annotations, spring will selectively skips the configuration based on the absence / presence of certain classes mentioned in the annotations.

This [link](https://roytuts.com/spring-conditionalonclass-and-conditionalonmissingclass/) (article) might help you to get more details on the same.